# Using Adorner to show stretched overlay containing UIElements

Tags: c#, wpf, adorner

I am using an `Adorner` to create an overlay when a button is clicked. This overlay contains a form, e.g. a login-form based on other `UIElement`s (`Button`, `TextBox` etc.).
Basically this is how it's done: [Click](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/28/wpf-adorners-part-2-ndash-placing-any-control-on-the.aspx)

But there is one problem. The overlay should fill the available space. So I set the `Vertical-`/`HorizontalAlignment` property of the Form's Panel (which is the Child of the `ControlAdorner`) to `Stretch`. However it only takes as much space as needed to show the Panel instead of using the whole available space.

I think this is why:
The `ControlAdorner`'s method `MeasureOverride` is called with the correct size (the available space). But then the Child's `Measure`-method is used to calculate the desired size. And that call seems to ignore the `Stretch` property. Probably because the Child has no `Parent` set, because the Child is generated dynamically.

Is there a way to achieve this `Stretch`-thing for the `Adorner`'s Child to work properly?

Comment: Do i understand you right, that from a user perspective the GUI should just switch to another panel when a button is clicked?

Comment: Simply put, yes. :) The Button is clicked and the Form-Panel pops up on top of all other `UIElement`s. The panel itself has a translucent background-color and contains the form. But I forgot to mention that the Button incl. the Overlay-Panel will be encapsulated in a separate UserControl (for reusabilty). So the result is kind of a gesture-friendly (for Kinect) ComboBox: the programmer just need to add this ComboBox and set the adorned element (for example KinectRegion's child) and gets a gesture-friendly ComboBox that will show the ComboBoxItems on top of the adorned element (stretched).

Comment: So the reason you go with an adorner is that you want to see a shade of the original UI around/underneath your login form... i see...

Comment: Are you using the AdornerLayer of your main window? Please show your code where you add the adorner...

Comment: I don't have access to the code right now (but tomorrow). But the xaml looks like this: The window contains a `KinectRegion`, which contains an `AdornerDecorator` (thus the overlay will be beneath the KinectRegion!), which contains a `KinectScrollViewer`, which contains a `Panel` that contains the mentioned Button/ComboBox-UserControl. The `KinectScrollViewer` then is passed to the `ControlAdorner`'s constructor, so the `KinectScrollViewer` is the adorned element.

Comment: And your login form should have the same size as the KinectScrollViewer or of the whole window?

Comment: If the login-form (in the adorner) should have the same size as the KinectScrollViewer (the adorned element), then your adorner's *MeasureOverride* should return the size based on the adorned element's *ActualWidth* and *ActualHeight* (you might need to cast `this.AdornedElement` to *FrameworkElement*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working :-)

Since the `Adorner`s `MeasureOverride` already computes the correct dimensions for overlaying the adorned element we don't need to override it. However we need to override `ArrangeOverride` because we need to call the `Arrange` method of the child. Otherwise it may not be shown.

So here's a working example code:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace AdornerTest {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            StackPanel overlayPanel = new StackPanel() {
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x99, 0, 0, 0xFF)),
            };

            // example content 1
            Rectangle overlayChild1 = new Rectangle() {
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)),
                Margin = new Thickness(10),
                Height = 50,
            };
            overlayPanel.Children.Add(overlayChild1);

            // example content 2
            Button overlayChild2 = new Button();
            overlayChild2.Content = "asdasd";
            overlayChild2.Margin = new Thickness(10);
            overlayPanel.Children.Add(overlayChild2);

            OverlayAdorner adorner = new OverlayAdorner(mainGrid) {
                Content = overlayPanel,
            };
            AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(mainGrid).Add(adorner);
        }
    }


    class OverlayAdorner : Adorner {
        private FrameworkElement _content;

        public OverlayAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
            : base(adornedElement) {
        }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount {
            get {
                return _content == null ? 0 : 1;
            }
        }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) {
            if (index != 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            return _content;
        }

        public FrameworkElement Content {
            get { return _content; }
            set {
                if (_content != null) {
                    RemoveVisualChild(_content);
                }
                _content = value;
                if (_content != null) {
                    AddVisualChild(_content);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize) {
            _content.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), finalSize));
            return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="AdornerTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <Grid Name="mainGrid">
            <Button Content="Show Overlay" Name="button" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</Window>
```